# Inhomogeneous second order PDE solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

We have the following equation:
$$u_{yy}-2u_{xy}+2u_x-u_y=4e^x$$
and we want to find its general solution. We have brought it to the canonical form:
$$-2u_{\xi\eta}+u_\xi=2e^\xi$$
where $\xi=x, \eta=x+2y$.

Our professor suggested to integrate it w.r.t. $\xi$ but we're not sure, and we don't know how to find the general solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: Write $v=\partial_\xi u$ to get it down to the first order equation $-2\partial_\eta v+v=2e^\xi$. This you can solve easily

Comment: @K.defaoite is that an ODE what I can solve with the method of variations of coefficients ? I'm sorry if this sounds dumb, but all my professors of this subject are ....awful and I don't understand much of what they say

Comment: You can solve it with an integrating factor.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating $-2u_{\xi\eta}+ u_{\xi}= 2e^{\xi}$ with respect to $\xi$, as suggested, $-2u_{\eta}+ u= 2e^{\xi}$.
Now that is the same as the ordinary differential equation, $-2u'+ u= const$. The associated homogeneous equation is $-2u'+ u= 0$ with characteristic equation $-2r+ 1= 0$ with characteristic root $r= 1/2$ so the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation is $u(\eta)= Ce^{\eta/2}$ where, since we are treating $\xi$ as a constant,
C can be an arbitrary function of $\xi$.

Since the non-homogeneous part, $e^{\xi}$, is a constant with respect to $\eta$ we look for a constant solution, u= D.  Then $-2u'+ u= D= e^{\xi}$. The general solution to the entire equation is $u(\xi,\eta)= C(\xi)e^{\eta/2}+ e^{\xi}$.

Comment: I agree with you, but somehow the answer looks like this: $u(x,y) = 2e^x+e^{\frac{1}{2}(x+2y)}(\varphi(x)+\psi(x+2y))$.